# How to specify the dotnet 6 runtime for aws lambda, using terraform?

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, .net-6.0, terraform-provider-aws

I can deploy a dotnetcore3.1 runtime using this input in my terraform (executed from GitLab CI pipeline):

```
variable "runtime" {
  type = string
  default = "dotnetcore3.1"
}
```

After it deploys, I can manually change the runtime from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6:

[image]

But how do I specify .NET 6 in the terraform to begin with?

I have tried:

```
variable "runtime" {
  type = string
  default = "dotnet6"
}
```

But I get the following error in my pipeline:

`Error: expected runtime to be one of [nodejs nodejs4.3 nodejs6.10 nodejs8.10 nodejs10.x nodejs12.x nodejs14.x java8 java8.al2 java11 python2.7 python3.6 python3.7 python3.8 dotnetcore1.0 dotnetcore2.0 dotnetcore2.1 dotnetcore3.1 nodejs4.3-edge go1.x ruby2.5 ruby2.7 provided provided.al2], got dotnet6`

How does one select the .NET 6 runtime in TF?

Comment: It would seem that .NET 6 isn't supported via Terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would seem that .NET 6 isn't supported via Terraform.

This is not entirely true, the AWS provider supports `dotnet6` runtime, you just have to have a version of the provider has support for it.

Currently the latest version of the AWS provider is `4.27.0`. The support for `dotnet6` was introduced around version `4.4.0`. Adjusting the provider to have a version greater than `4.4.0` should be enough to have `dotnet6` support.

So you would want to modify your `required_providers` block to something like this:

```hcl
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">=4.4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet6` works just fine.

I suspect your TF version and/or AWS provider are out of date.  I'm using `dotnet6` for a lmabda just fine with the following..

```
"terraformVersions": {
    "terraformMajorVersion": "1",
    "providerVersions": {
        "aws": "4.14.0",
    }
```

Comment: any way you can share how this really works in production?  I am trying to wrap my head around how to create infrastructure and tie it code in another repo that needs to be build and published.